# How to create a border between the line numbers and text in Vim

Tags: terminal, vim

I'd like to have a thin border line to the right of the line numbers and to the left of the text.

Answer (score 5):

You might use different color to highlight `LineNr`. For example:

```
:hi LineNr   cterm=bold ctermbg=gray ctermfg=black gui=bold guibg=gray guifg=white
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's possible.

However, you can make the gutter wider.

```
:set numberwidth=3
```

Comment: this works for adding gutter to the left of the numbers, but not to the right. is there a way to do that?